# Fine Uploader - Combine scaled image with autoUpload:false and custom filename Not Working

Tags: scaling, fine-uploader

I'm using fine-uploader 5.0.6 to upload images to my amazon s3 account, where i have the following option set:

```
autoUpload: false
validation: max 10mb, min 400kb
custom filename
```

as below:

```
var manualuploader = jQuery("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderS3({
    ...,
    autoUpload: false,
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
        sizeLimit: 10000000, // 10mb
        minSizeLimit: 400000 // 400kb
    },
    objectProperties: {
        key: function (fileId) {
            var filename = jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploader('getName', fileId);
            var uuid = jQuery('#fine-uploader').fineUploader('getUuid', fileId);
            var ext = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            design_name = design_name.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '');
            folder_name = design_name.replace(/\s/g, '-');
            return artist + '/' + folder_name + '/original.' + ext;
        }
    }
    ...
});

jQuery('#triggerUpload').click(function() {
    manualuploader.fineUploaderS3('uploadStoredFiles');
});
```

This is working as expected but now i need to include a 500px scaled image to upload at the same time onto s3. I know i can do this with the `scaling` object but it doesn't work with my code. Having tried several methods i seem to have got it down to these problems:

When i add the following in :

```
    scaling: {
        sizes: [
            {name: "web", maxSize: 500}
        ]
    }
```

Only the original/main file gets uploaded onto the s3 server, not both as intended. If i use `sendOriginal: false` then the 'web' version does get sent to the server.

Also where i change the filename in `objectProperties{key` so that it becomes

```
artist/folder/original.ext
```

i also need to be able to have the smaller web version follow the same structure so it's:

```
artist/folder/web.ext
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What version of fine Uploader?

Comment: i was using 5.0.3. Having just checked i can see there is a new 5.0.6 which i have just downloaded and put it place. Now when i add scaling it uploads rather than alerts me for 'No files to upload' but the small image doesn't upload. I tried removing the size limit and it still doesn't

Comment: The size limit is a required property of the scaling option. If you are seeing a specific bug in Fine Uploader, please open up a case in the issue tracker.  Otherwise please describe the problem you are trying to solve a bit more here.

Comment: @RayNicholus sorry, to clarify the size limit i am talking about isn't the maxSize property in the scalings sizes [] but the minSizeLimit in validation. Can i confirm whether the minSizeLimit effects the scaled image? As my scaled image of maxSize:490 will always be below my 400kb minimum size limit. Have updated the initial question to try and explain more

Comment: `validation.minSizeLimit` doesn't affect scaled versions, since we don't know the size of the scaled versions at the time of validation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the issue you have reported with scaling or validation.  You can change the key name of your file, as you are already doing, via the `objectProperties.key` option.  You should be able to look at the original name of the file to determine if it is an original, or a scaled version.

Comment: Having looked into this and redone all my code over the weekend it now works, not sure what caused it. On the changing filename i currently search the filename for an indexOf (web) to determine which file which can be seen in this: http://pastebin.com/jTi0bBYC and also the same concept on the complete - temp.responseLink. Is this what you mean or is there an easier way?